# "NSURL URLWithString" method not returning nil for invalid URL string

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10

I am facing an issue with "NSURL URLWithString" method,

I am expecting to get nil while using the above method if the url string is invalid. But its returning empty value instead.

I have attached the code sample below.

```
NSString *sampleURLString = @"";
NSURL *sampleURL = [NSURL URLWithString:sampleURLString];

NSLog(@"Sample url string : %@", sampleURLString);
NSLog(@"Sample url : %@", sampleURL);
```

**Additional information:**

- I am using XCode Version 8.1.
- I have also tested in iOS version
  (8,9,10) in device and simulator.
- As of now I have handled this by using "canOpenURL" to check the resulted NSURL and avoided further execution. But I need to know why this issue occurs.

Comment: sampleURLString pass your url here

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya : When passing any URL like "http://www.google.com" "URLWithString" function is working correctly and returning a valid NSURL, but only when I pass empty url string as above I am not getting nil as its supposed to be.

Comment: are you working with webview ?

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya : Yes, I am.

Comment: then you must have to update your question with UIwevbviewDelagates method

Comment: @Bharath did you got it ?

Comment: Looks strange for me as well. I assumed to use this factory method to check for correct `stringURL` passed from elsewhere: `BOOL isValidURL = ([NSURL URLWithString:baseUrl] != nil) ? YES : NO;`, but seems I can't...

Answer (score -1):

**Objective C**

```
[NSURL URLWithString:[urlStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

**Swift**

```
let url = NSURL(string: urlString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!)
```

Answer (score -2):

You are assigning an empty string. 
Check the length of your string to know is it empty or not.

```
NSString *sampleURLString = @"";
    if (sampleURLString.length <=0) {
        sampleURLString = nil;

    }
    NSURL *sampleURL = [NSURL URLWithString:sampleURLString];

    NSLog(@"Sample url string : %@", sampleURLString);
    NSLog(@"Sample url : %@", sampleURL);
```

**Output:**

Sample url string : (null)

Sample url : (null)

```
If you want to validate a URL

if (sampleURL && sampleURL.scheme && sampleURL.host) {

    NSLog(@"valid: %@", sampleURLString);

} else{

NSLog(@"Invalid: %@", sampleURLString);
}
```